# *Malformed access token - but it's the token i get (PHP)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, malformed

i have this problem with my FB-App

i have 2 files..
1) the mainApp.php .. and ..
2) the asyncApp.php .. (which processes data, delivers content & shit..)

and now..

- when a user logs in, everything works fine.. i get the access-token and save it to a SESSION-Var..(only mainApp.php is processed here).. but..
- when i call the async.php via jquery.load() e.g. .. i always get the 
  {"error":{"message":"Malformed access token .. oO

but the token is the same i get from FB in the mainApp.php.. :(

mainApp:
this way i get the Token..

```
if(isset($_GET["code"])) {
                $code = $_GET["code"];    
                $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$appID.'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($appRedirectURI).'&client_secret='.$appSecret.'&code='.$code;
                $curl_handle=curl_init();                   
                curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,6);
                curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);                  
                curl_close($curl_handle); 

                if(strpos($buffer, 'access_token=') === 0) {                        
                    //if you requested offline acces save this token to db for use later                        
                    $token = str_replace('access_token=', '', $buffer);
                    $_SESSION['fbToken'] = $token;
```

later i call the async.php which should do a feed on the users wall..

```
$attachment =  array(
                        'access_token' => $_SESSION['fbToken'],
                        'message' => 'dfdfdf',
                        'name' => 'sdfdsf',
                        'link' => 'http://www.mbla.de',
                        'description' => 'sdfdsf',
                        'picture'=> '',
                        'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))
                        );

                        $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed');
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
                        $result = curl_exec($ch);
                        curl_close ($ch);
```

would be nice if someone could help me.. i'm suffering almost 2 weeks now.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

---

1. What happens when you call `async.php` directly, does it work?
2. What happens when you have the script `print_r()` the contents of `$_SESSION`, is it populated?

   - What about if you do it through an ajax call, and inspect the output through Firebug/Chrome Inspector?

Looking at the code attached (`async.php`), it looks like you're not passing in the parameters properly to Facebook. The curl option `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` does not take an array as an argument. Instead, it should be constructed as a query string:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'param1=value&param2=value&param3=value');
```

For ease, I tend to do this instead:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, htmlspecialchars(http_build_query(array(
    "param1" => 'value',
    "param2" => 'value',
    "param3" => 'value'
))));
```